# Extract the multiple patterns from the text file in python (Single def function)

Tags: python, text, extract

My text file contains below information. from that i want to extract the multiple patterns with the single def function can you please help me on this

pattern1:print that particular line which contains **STALL** keyword

patter2: print the lines which contains **OVERRUN** keyword

pattern3:print the lines which contains two keyword **SIM DASD** and **ALERT** keyword

pattern4: print the lines which contains **“SNAP”** and **“IS-“** and endup with the lines which contains the keyword **END OF DISPLAY**

```
Input:
08:12:19 80000000 00000000 2967561E      
08:12:19 PGM-BA13 CODE-U00BA1302 TERM-000000A 
08:12:19 SNAP 0003I 08.12.20 CPU-A SS-BSS SSU-BSS IS-3 
08:12:19 PSW-07151000 80000000 00000000 2967561E      
08:12:19 PGM-BA13 CODE-U00BA1302 TERM-000000A        
08:12:19 END OF  DISPLAY 
23:34:16 CYEM0099E 23.34.16 SIM DASD   MODERATE ALERT 
20:10:25 CYEM0099E 20.10.25 OVERRUN
13:48:54 CYED0012W  MODULE QUEUE FOR MAY BE STALL
```

Output should be:

```
pattern1:
13:48:54 CYED0012W  MODULE QUEUE FOR MAY BE STALL

patter2:  
20:10:25 CYEM0099E 20.10.25 OVERRUN

pattern3:
23:34:16  CYEM0099E 23.34.16 SIM DASD   MODERATE ALERT 

patter4:
08:12:19 SNAP0003I 08.12.20 CPU-A SS-BSS SSU-BSS IS-3 
08:12:19 PSW-07151000 80000000 00000000 2967561E      
08:12:19 PGM-BA13 CODE-U00BA1302 TERM-000000A        
08:12:19 END OF  DISPLAY
```

I have used this code

```
value=["STALL","OVERRUN"]
with open('SNAP.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if value in line:
           print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need patterns here. `"substring" in "string"` or `"substring" in line` and `line.endswith("suffix")`should work fine.